# SQL - multiple rows with one column into one row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
select convert(varchar(32),tas.complete_by_dt,101)+': '+tas.notes [Task] 
from TX_SOL_TASK tas where customer_no=230459
```

and it is returning one row for each value, while I wish to just have one row with a column for each value.  Here is was what currently returns:

```
Task

08/07/2013: Called Jane for lunch of she is in town

08/19/2013: Jane is NY and will talk with her acct the end of August. Will know then escat amount and hoping by the end of 1st qtr.

09/09/2013: Jane called and requested info to send her check through Fidelity. She is at Canyon Ranch this week. Emailed her info.

09/24/2013: Thank you!

11/06/2013: Called Jane for lunch with MD and mf, she is trasveling after this week. Call her 12/9 to see if we can do that week!

11/13/2013: Sent Jane happy thought for another sucessful Hats in The Garden!
```

Comment: What is your engine? SQL Server?

Comment: For SQL, if you want to turn rows into columns you'll want to read more about [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) functionality.

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Try this dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @customer_no INT = 230459;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @cols += STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),complete_by_dt,101))
                       FROM dbo.TX_SOL_TASK 
                       WHERE customer_no = @customer_no
                       GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),complete_by_dt,101)
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SET @sql = N'SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),complete_by_dt,101) Completed,
                notes
        FROM dbo.TX_SOL_TASK
        WHERE customer_no = @customer_no
        ) AS d
  PIVOT (MIN([notes]) FOR [Completed] IN (' + @cols + ')) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@customer_no INT', @customer_no;
```